# Trouble with Loading Tidycensus data

Tags: r, tidycensus

I am trying to load variable data in with tidycensus but am running into a pervasive error.

```
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyverse)
census_api_key("My key is here")

poverty <- get_acs(geography = "block group", variables = "B17021",
                state = "MO", county = "St. Louis City", geometry = TRUE)
```

The error I get is this.

```
Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 
'character'
```

I have made sure I am running up to date packages and have input my Census API Key, but the error persists. Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access variables through the Census Bureau API without specifying what "row" and "column" you want. From table `B17021` [you have many options](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=bkmk); one such option you could select would be the `Estimate` (column) of `Income in the past 12 months below poverty level` (row). In general, the format of properly formatted variable names is `TableName_VariableNumberType`. So for the example I just gave:

- Table = `B17021`
- Row = `002`
- Type = `estimate` (`E`)

The variable this corresponds to is `"B17021_002E"`.

However, it's best to simply consult the relevant [API documentation](https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs5/variables.html) to make sure you have the correct variable name. Table `B17021` begins about halfway down the page, and you can cross-reference this guide against what you see the in the American FactFinder to make sure you have the right variable name.

As an aside, I wrote myself a guide about this a couple of years ago for Python. It is slightly out of date, but I have posted it to [my GitHub](https://github.com/HFBrowning/EnvEpi/blob/133799920fe9b846c2e63da3b7e382d316d8fa70/Census%20Bureau%20API%20Guide.pdf) in case it might help.

**Edit**: It appears that `get_acs` does not *require* you put in the variable type. If you do not, the data that are returned have all attributes, which allows you to separately plot estimate, margin of error, from the same object. That's a nice feature!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @HFBrowning is great.  Also: you can use the `table` parameter instead of the `variables` parameter to request all variables from a given table, which will allow your supplied code to work.  For example:

```
poverty <- get_acs(geography = "block group", table = "B17021",
                   state = "MO", county = "St. Louis City", geometry = TRUE)
```

works, and allows you to get variables `B17021_001` through `B17021_035` without specifying them individually.